# Transform XHTML with XML::Saxon::XSLT2

Tags: java, perl, xhtml, xslt-2.0, saxon

I'm trying to get a simple XSLT 2.0 transformation running using perl and XML::Saxon::XSLT2. Here's what i've tried so far:

test.xhtml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>My Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>My Content</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

test.xslt:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

xslttest.pl:

```perl
use strictures;
use diagnostics;
use XML::Saxon::XSLT2;
use XML::LibXML;

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new;
my $xsl = 'test.xslt';
my $xslt = $parser->load_xml( location => $xsl );
my $dom = $parser->load_xml( location => 'test.xhtml' );
my $trans = XML::Saxon::XSLT2->new($xslt);
my $output = $trans->transform( $dom, 'xhtml' );
print $output;
```

Output of `locate saxon9he.jar`:

```sh
/usr/local/share/java/saxon9he.jar
/usr/share/java/saxon9he.jar
```

Now, if i run `perl xslttest.pl`, i get:

```
Uncaught exception from user code:

    A problem was encountered while attempting to compile and install your Inline
    Java code. The command that failed was:
      "/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/javac" -deprecation  -d "/tmp/perltest/_Inline/lib/auto/XML/Saxon/XSLT2_dbc0" Transformer.java > cmd.out 2>&1

    The build directory was:
    /tmp/perltest/_Inline/build/XML/Saxon/XSLT2_dbc0

    The error message was:
    Transformer.java:1: error: package net.sf.saxon.s9api does not exist
    import net.sf.saxon.s9api.*;
    ^
    Transformer.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
        private XsltExecutable xslt;
                ^
      symbol:   class XsltExecutable
      location: class Transformer
    Transformer.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
        private Processor proc;
                ^
      symbol:   class Processor
      location: class Transformer
    Transformer.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
        private HashMap<String, XdmAtomicValue> params;
                                ^
    (...)
```

Perl version (result of `perl -v`):

```
This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 2 (v5.18.2) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
(with 41 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)
(...)
```

Why does the transformation fail? It seems that Inline::Java fails to compile the required code (???), but how to avoid this?

EDIT:

The `net.sf.saxon.s9api.*` classes are provided by the `saxon9he.jar` itself:

```sh
$ jar tvf /usr/share/java/saxon9he.jar | grep net.sf.saxon.s9api
     0 Wed Aug 06 10:34:58 CEST 2014 net/sf/saxon/s9api/
  1805 Wed Aug 06 10:34:58 CEST 2014 net/sf/saxon/s9api/Axis.class
   302 Wed Aug 06 10:34:58 CEST 2014 net/sf/saxon/s9api/BuildingContentHandler.class
   421 Wed Aug 06 10:34:58 CEST 2014 net/sf/saxon/s9api/BuildingStreamWriter.class
  1207 Wed Aug 06 10:34:58 CEST 2014 net/sf/saxon/s9api/BuildingStreamWriterImpl.class
  2025 Wed Aug 06 10:34:58 CEST 2014 net/sf/saxon/s9api/ConstructedItemType.class
  1130 Wed Aug 06 10:34:58 CEST 2014 net/sf/saxon/s9api/DOMDestination.class
   303 Wed Aug 06 10:34:58 CEST 2014 net/sf/saxon/s9api/Destination.class
  1367 Wed Aug 06 10:34:58 CEST 2014 net/sf/saxon/s9api/DocumentBuilder$BuildingContentHandlerImpl.class
  8981 Wed Aug 06 10:34:58 CEST 2014 net/sf/saxon/s9api/DocumentBuilder.class
   455 Wed Aug 06 10:34:58 CEST 2014 net/sf/saxon/s9api/ExtensionFunction.class
(...)
```

Comment: Have you installed the net.sf.saxon.s9api Java library?

Comment: @choroba: Thanks for your comment - `net.sf.saxon.s9api.*` is part of the `saxon9he.jar`, so it should be available for `Inline::Java`.

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=612894 maybe?

Comment: I've found this already, but i don't know how to tell Inline::Java about the classpath, since i don't `use Inline::Java` directly in my `xslttest.pl`. And It seems that `saxon9he.jar` is available to `Inline::Java`, since it tries to do something with its `Transformer` class...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script works for me, and produces the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <title>My Title</title>
   </head>
   <body>

      <p>My Content</p>

   </body>
</html>
```

(Though it's not exactly fast. I'd forgotten how slow Inline::Java stuff was.)

I have the following installed (on Ubuntu 14.04):

- Perl 5.20
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.1) (7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.14.04.2), installed in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/`
- Saxon HE 9.5.1.7, located at `/usr/share/java/saxon9he.jar`
- Inline::Java 0.53
- XML::Saxon::XSLT2 0.007

Do you have similar versions? Did you install Inline::Java correctly (you need to set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable). Did you run the tests that came with it? Did they pass? (If you used a CPAN client to install Inline::Java, it would normally run the test cases and only install the module if it passed, unless you explicitly override this behaviour.)

Similarly, did you run the [test case that comes with XML::Saxon::XSLT2](https://metacpan.org/source/TOBYINK/XML-Saxon-XSLT2-0.007/t/01basic.t)? Did it pass? (Because it does something fairly similar to your test script.)

Comment: Oh - thats interesting. I'm using oracle java and i've installed all the perl modules using the deb packages (via synaptic). Maybe i should remove them and use cpan.

Comment: I've you've installed package via your system package manager, you're trusting the person who packaged them to have tested them sufficiently. (The Debian packagers tend to be pretty good.) Rather than removing these packages and re-installing them from CPAN, you could try downloading the tarballs, extracting the test suites, and running them from the command line. (To do so, just `cd` into the tarball's root directory, and execute `prove -rv "t/"`.)

Comment: Thank you - i will do so. I appreciate your help!